# Facing problem while installing "dbus package" using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, dbus

I want to use windows notifications in python. I installed "notify2" package. It demanded to install "dbus" package as well. Following error occurred while installing the package.
How to get rid of it?

[image: installation error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notify2` won't work on Windows – it's for environments using Dbus for notification messaging (mainly Linux desktop environments).

For Windows, you'll probably want the [`win10toast`](https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/) library instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed win10toast. still i could not import that in my .py file.     Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\guj5cob\pycharmprojects\newtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg (from win10toast) (40.8.0)                                                                                                                             import win10toast gives me error saying that the module is not found. Could you please help?